# SwiftUI - Segment Control with Lists

Tags: swiftui, xcode11

Im trying to make a Segment Control that handles Lists and/or Vstacks

I was able to make a Segment Control with text, but not Lists

```
import SwiftUI

struct MaterialSegmentControl : View {
    @State private var MaterialType = 0

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {

            VStack {
                SegmentedControl(selection: $MaterialType) {
                    Text("Style").tag(0)
                    Text("Text").tag(1)
                    Text("Arrange").tag(2)

                }
                Text("Value: \(MaterialType)")


            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I have a Segment Control that switched between Lists and/or  Vstacks?

Comment: What happens when you use a properly coded set of `List()` elements? By properly coded, I mean you can get each list to display *outside* of a `SegmentedControl()`.

Comment: You mean creating Lists in different files, and pointing to SegmentedControl()?

Would you mind sharing some code on how you think of doing that?

Sorry, but I am a designer newbie to code... : )

Comment: To me, it looks like you have an answer. I was asking two things, based on you having three `Text()` views working properly. (1) Are your `List()` views working properly? If you remove the `SegmentedControl()` from the equation and try to display a single list, does it work? And (2) if so, what happens when you embed things in a SegmentedControl? It sounds to me like you don't need to worry about separate files (yet). Eventually you may want to break things down, and that is easily doable. That's a whole different question though. Good luck!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes! It's pretty straightforward. Something like this:

```swift
struct MaterialSegmentControl : View {
    @State private var MaterialType = 0

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {

            VStack {
                SegmentedControl(selection: $MaterialType) {
                    Text("Style").tag(0)
                    Text("Text").tag(1)
                    Text("Arrange").tag(2)
                }

                if MaterialType == 0 {
                    List {
                        Text("Hi")
                        Text("\(MaterialType)")
                    }
                } else if MaterialType == 1 {
                    List {
                        Text("Beep")
                        Text("\(MaterialType)")
                    }
                } else {
                    List {
                        Text("Boop")
                        Text("\(MaterialType)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @piebie how would the code change if I needed the segmented control in a scrollview?